# Evaluate $\int \cosh^3 (x) \sinh^2 (x )dx $

Tags: integration, hyperbolic-functions, trigonometric-integrals

> Evaluate $$\int \cosh^3 (x)  \sinh^2 (x )dx $$

So my original thought was to apply the identity that $\sinh^2(x)=\cosh^2(x)-1$. This means that my integral becomes
$$\int \cosh^5(x)-\cosh^3(x) dx$$
which is worse to integrate I think. What would be the best approach to tackle this or where can i go from here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Further to the better but more imaginative strategies of other answers, $\int\frac{(e^x+e^{-x})^3(e^x-e^{-x})^2}{32}dx$ requires no thought, just routine calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u=\sinh(x)$. Then $du=\cosh(x)dx$. Hence, the integral is 
$$\int (u^2+1)u^2du.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use that $$\cosh^3(x)\cdot \sinh^2(x)=\frac{1}{16} (-2 \cosh (x)+\cosh (3 x)+\cosh (5 x))$$

Comment: This is hardly the approach that a usual human being would take.

Comment: Where did you get that from?

Comment: @H.Linkhorn By product-to-sum and double-angle formulas, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this could simply be solved using the simple identities:
$$2\cosh(x)=e^{x}+e^{-x}, \quad 2\cosh(x)=e^{x}-e^{-x}.$$
For the product $$\cosh^3(x)\sinh ^2(x)=\bigg(\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}\bigg)^3\bigg(\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}\bigg)^2$$ $$=\frac{1}{32}\big(e^{3x}+e^{-3x}+3(e^{x}-e^{-x})\big)\big(e^{2x}+e^{-2x}-2\big)$$
Expanding the two brackets one obtains:
$$\cosh^3(x)\sinh ^2(x)=\frac{1}{32}[(e^{5x}+e^{-5x})+(e^{3x}+e^{-3x})-2(e^{x}+e^{-x})]$$ $$=\frac{1}{32}(2\cosh(5x)+\cosh(3x)-2\cosh (x)).$$
Now they are in a simplified form and easy for integration. On integration of both sides of the above equation we obtain:
$$\int\cosh^3(x)\sinh ^2(x)dx=\frac{1}{32}\bigg[ \frac{2\sinh(5x)}{5}+\frac{2\sinh(3x)}{3}-2\sinh(x)\bigg]+\text{constant.}$$
That's it.